# Для чего нужны динамические библиотеки и как их создать на обычном Си?

Tags: c

По заданию нужно реализовать программу в динамической библиотеке, но почему то материал из интернета не смог помочь мне. До сих пор не понял зачем они нужны, как создать их для программы.

Answer (score 1):

Динамические библиотеки (dll/so) содержат функции, которые загружаются в ОЗУ только в тот момент, когда они **реально** понадобились.

А функции из статических библиотек прикомпоновываются к исполнимому модулю заранее, не зависимо от того, будут ли они вызваны, или нет.

Экономия памяти получается весьма существенная. Но это не главное достоинство динамических библиотек. Дело в том, что функция из динамической библиотеки одна на весь комп. И она, как правило, последней версии. Поэтому, **все** программы будут использовать именно эту одну, новейшую версию функции.

А компоновка исполняемого модуля могла быть выполнена 10 лет назад и какя там версия - одному богу известно.

Создание динамической библиотеки не представляет никакого труда. Если вы пользуетесь *gcc*, то просто нужно добавить флаги -fPIC и -shared

Более подробно можно посмотреть тут:

https://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/shared_lib_intro.txt.html

Answer (score 0):

Динамические библиотеки на то и динамические, что ты их можешь включать во время run-time'а:

Заголовок от либы (`lib.h`):

```c
#pragma once

int __stdcall add(int a, int b);
```

Библиотека (`lib.c`):

```c
#include "lib.h"

// no inlining
int __stdcall add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Exe-main ('main.c')(скипнуты обработки ошибок):

```c
// src -> inc\lib.h
#include "..\inc\lib.h"
#include <windows.h>
// or #include <libloaderapi.h>

#ifdef UNICODE
#   undef UNICODE
#endif

// src -> lib\lib.dll
static const TCHAR LIB_PATH = TEXT("..\dll\lib.dll");
static const TCHAR ADD_FUNC_NAME = TEXT("add");

typedef int (*summator)(int a, int b);

int main() {
    HMODULE libModule = LoadLibrary(LIB_PATH);
    summator summator = GetProcAddress(libModule, ADD_FUNC_NAME);

    printf("%d", summator(2, 3));

    FreeLibrary(libModule);
}
```